# How to toggle a variable in a loop

Tags: c++

Variable `i` toggles between `2` and `3` and multiplied into `a`, as in the following example:

```
a=2;
a=a*i // a=2*2=4    i=2
a=a*i // a=4*3=12   i=3
a=a*i // a=12*2=24  i=2
a=a*i // a=24*3=72  i=3
```

which goes on as long as `a` is < `1000`.

How can I give the `i` two values sequentially as shown in the example?

Comment: @ChrisLaplante They are values based on his code. They are very appropriate in code ticks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int a = 2, i = 2;
while( a < 1000 )
{
    a *= i;
    i = 5 - i;
}
```

and many other ways.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use a loop

```
int a = 2;
bool flip = true;

while (a < 1000)
{
    a *= flip ? 2 : 3;
    flip = !flip;
}
```

Comment: I think flip should be initialized to true at the start. In the op's example, a is multiplied by 2 then 3, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have i be equal to two values at the same time. You can however make i alternate between 2 and 3 until a < 1000. Below is the code;

```
int a = 2;
int counter = 0;
while (a < 1000) {
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        a *= 2;
    }
    else {
        a *= 3;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Better to use a for loop here. It will keep counter in the loop scope and is also more readable since your use case is clearly what for was designed to do. Also use ++counter as you do not need a local copy of counter.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean. It would be much more concise had I done it.

Comment: Just some stylistic stuff to make the OP's question a bit more interesting.

Comment: This is really verbose and results in duplicate instructions if not optimized by the compiler correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick solution that doesn't involve a conditional.

```
int c = 0;
while (a < 1000)
    a *= (c++ % 2) + 2;
```

or even

```
for(int c = 0; a < 1000; c++)
    a *= (c % 2) + 2;
```

The modulo is found, which results in either a `0` or a `1` and then shifted up by 2 resulting in either `2` or `3`.

---

Here's another efficient way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int its_bacon_time;
  int i = ++(its_bacon_time = 0);
  int y = 18;
  int z = 9;
  bool flag = !false;
  int sizzle;
  typedef bool decision_property;
  #define perhaps (decision_property)(-42*42*-42)
  #ifdef perhaps
  # define YUM -
  # define YUMMM return
  #endif
  bool bacon = !(bool) YUM(sizzle = 6);
  if(flag)
    std::cout << "YEP" << std::endl;
  while (flag) {
    if (bacon = !bacon)
      flag = !flag; // YUM()?
    if (YUM((YUM-i)YUM(i*2))+1>=((0x1337|0xECC8)&0x3E8))
      (*((int*)&flag)) &= 0x8000;
    else
      flag = perhaps;
    std::cout << i << " ";
    int multiplicative_factor = y / (bacon ? z : y);
    int* temporal_value_indicator = &i;
    (**(&temporal_value_indicator)) *=
      (((((multiplicative_factor & 0x0001) > 0) ? sizzle : bacon) // ~yum~
      << 1) ^ (bacon? 0 : 15));
    std::cout << (((((multiplicative_factor & 0x0001) > 0) ? sizzle : bacon) // ~yum~
      << 1) ^ (bacon? 0 : 15)) << std::endl;
  }

  YUMMM its_bacon_time;
}
```

<sup>Point is that you should probably try something yourself first before asking for something that is **really simple** to achieve.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  int multiplier;
  for (int i = 0; a < 1000; ++i)
  {
    multiplier = (i % 2) ? 2 : 3;
    a *= multiplier;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile; you can't have two typed declarations in a for loop's initializer.

Comment: It should be `a *= multiplier`; Your semicolon is also missing.

Comment: Oh shoot, I typed it up quickly on my phone. Then I edited my post to move the multiplier into the for loop initializer list. Guess I forgot that C++ doesn't have that Java cool-ness. Updated, and now the code compiles.